# Pagination for a SQL Query Template

Tags: sql-server

For my application I created a **SQL query builder** which has got **Where** and **Order By** clauses. I would like to know how to paginate through the results i.e. I would like to get a template on how to paginate through the results of a SQL query. This description may be a bit confusing, so it may be easier with an example:

Consider the **Test Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [RecordID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Dept] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] 
    SELECT 1, N'1', N'Andy', N'IT'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, N'2', N'Bob', N'IT'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, N'3', N'Camila', N'Sales'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, N'4', N'Drew', N'IT'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, N'5', N'Elsie', N'Sales'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, N'6', N'Frank', N'IT'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, N'7', N'Gaby', N'Sales'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, N'8', N'Hank', N'IT'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, N'9', N'Iris', N'Sales'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, N'8', N'John', N'IT'
```

Let us say that I have a **Where** Clause as:

```
WHERE  ([Dept] = 'IT')
```

And an **Order By** Clause as:

```
ORDER BY [Name] DESC
```

I am attempting to do the pagination by using something like:

```
SELECT [RECORDID], [ID], [Name], [Dept], RowNum  
    FROM (
            SELECT [RECORDID], [ID], [Name], [Dept], 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [RecordID]) AS RowNum 
            FROM [TestTable] WHERE  ([Dept] = 'IT') 
        ) AS [TestTable_DerivedTable] 
WHERE [TestTable_DerivedTable].RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 6 ORDER BY [Name] DESC
```

This does not work because I cannot get the `ORDER BY [Name] DESC` into `[TestTable_DerivedTable]`. 
If I just had the **WHERE** clause, it would return the names:

> Andy, Bob, Drew, Frank, Hank, and John.

If I put in the pagination i.e. **BETWEEN 3 AND 6**, I correctly get:

> Drew, Frank, Hank, and John

How do I add the `ORDER BY [Name] DESC` so that I get *(first the reversal, then the pagination)*:

> Frank, Drew, Bob, and Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the `ORDER BY [Name] DESC` into the Window function, you will get what you want:

```
SELECT [RECORDID], [ID], [Name], [Dept], RowNum  
FROM
(
   SELECT [RECORDID], [ID], [Name], [Dept]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name] DESC) AS RowNum 
   FROM [TestTable] WHERE  ([Dept] = 'IT') 
) AS [TestTable_DerivedTable] 
WHERE [TestTable_DerivedTable].RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 6
```